# How to retry a request after catch a 401 status?

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I would like to know how is this possible to return a request result after the second try.

- Steps

  - 1: Make a request
  - 2: Request is returning a status code 401 (not logged)
  - 3: Display login form (click login)
  - 4: Trigger an event, catch this event and retry the last failed request
  - 5: Returning the result of request directly in the component who failed the request

For this i am using [HttpInterceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor)

So step 1, 2 ,3 ,4 are working but not the last one !

```
 intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
return next.handle(request)
  .pipe(
    tap(() => {}, 
      (err: any) => {
      if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
        if (err.status === 401) {
          // display login form
          this.displayLoginForm();

          // Subscribe event 
          this.store.select('retry').subscribe((data) => {
            if (data) {
              const req = request.clone({
                setHeaders: {
                  Authorization: `Bearer ${this.globalDataService.token}`
                }
              });
              // Retry the last request
              return next.handle(req).subscribe((data) => {
                if (data instanceof HttpResponse) {
               // There i am getting the result of the working request
                  console.log(data.body);
           // ???? What to do to get the result in my component var ?
                }
              });
            }
          });
        } 

      }
    })
  );
```

}

Comment: any component /service can make the same request, so you have to link component/service with request

Comment: I think you missunderstanding what i need, each time i get a 401, i need to retry the last request after the login form.

Comment: "// ???? What to do to get the result in my component var ?", is this your question?

Comment: Yes but how can you know in which components and which variable should take the result ?

Comment: that is the first question I am asking you :)

Comment: I think you can always cache last visited path, by listening on route change & filtering out login.